# What component: a glass tube wrapped with a wire mesh and has a single metal pole inside?

Tags: repair, tube

[image: unknown tube wrapped in wire mesh]

[image: unknown tube glowing, buzzing]

I found this while trying to fix my noisy hot/cold water dispenser. It has a blueish glow and makes a loud buzzing noise of around 56-58 Hz.

I'm planning to replace it, but there doesn't seem to be writing anywhere on it. **Are there ways of testing to identify the specs of this component?**

**What is this?**

*My guess is that it's some sort of vacuum tube amp (if those are even used anymore). All of the Google keywords I used to search are within this post, but I couldn't find it.*

Please, and thanks!

*Update: It was actually this...*

[image: unknown coil thing]

*... that was causing the lamp to buzz while making some noise itself. I'm not sure what this is either.*

Comment: The new component is an [inductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction).

Comment: The coil you now show was likely part of a high frequency high voltage supply for the UV lamp.  If you remove or replace these parts use caution as the nearby wires and circuits may have very high voltages on them.  In some newer high voltage supplies components like these are often sealed in epoxy, wax, or covered with a silicone sealant which insulates them and reduces noise.

Comment: It's a high-volt transformer.  At resonant high-freqs.  So, a Tesla coil, modern industrial version.  Same device powers the cfl lamps in your laptop and widescreen TV.  If noisy, it might be arcing inside, from dirt & humidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not exposed to the water, then it is used to make ozone and kill all airborne bacteria and virus and oxidize any organic compounds. It works fine for that and UV lamps are using in bio-labs and lots of places where they need to destroy organics.

There used to be mercury vapor lamps in clothes washers and they did not need the high voltage. Hardware stores some places may still have the replacement bulbs that fit a standard light bulb base.

It might have been meant to make ozone that diffuses into the water. But ozone lasts for a very short time in water. Despite this, there are a lot of people selling ozone generators to purify water that are of dubious efficacy.

The noisy part is a high voltage coil like a mini Tesla Coil. Some cement that holds the copper coils in place probably failed. They will buzz at the mains frequency if they get loose.

Comment: Is it then wrong to store food under a UV lamp of it oxidizes organic compounds? I'm dubious of the purpose of this lower compartment.

Comment: @kelvinilla No, especially if it is in a wrapper. The lamp looks like it makes fairly long wave UV and it won't penetrate much in the way of plastic or paper. Bacteria are easily damaged and virus are practically blown apart. The real benefit is more likely to come from the UV ionizing oxygen to get ozone, which is a powerful oxidizer. Ozone is right up there with hydrogen peroxide and fluorine and will tear molecules up good. Ozone will kill bigger bugs than chlorine, like protozoa (giardia). Googling details is a waste - the ozone water treatment industry has saturated the web. Food is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a UV lamp, for water sterilization purposes. Don't look at it for too long.

Comment: It does look like a lamp; that makes sense.  It's placed on the ceiling of a storage compartment below the water dispenser assembly, which I don't use. Can you tell if it's a non-essential component so I can simply remove it? It's just that it's gotten noisy.

Comment: Yes, germicidal lamp, can cause sunburn or eye problems.

Comment: It is, strictly speaking, non-essential for the *operation* of the dispenser, but it does prevent the water *inside* the dispenser from becoming "bioactive". I recommend replacing it, if not with the same device then with a similar lamp.

Comment: @wbeaty Since I don't use the storage compartment anyway, do you think it's safe enough to simply remove it from the circuit? I just want to get rid of the noise it makes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The lamp is placed in an enclosure below the water assembly, separated by a metal partition plus the metal water tank itself. It doesn't seem like it's used for the water. I'm not sure though if there are properties of UV that allow it still permeate despite distance and metal. Considering its placement, do you think it's safe to remove?

Comment: If you do dispose of this lamp, note that it may be an old style high mercury content lamp, so to be environmentally correct you may want to call a local recycling center for proper disposal.

Comment: The original water dispenser may have had a glass or clear plastic supply line running close to the UV bulb for sterilization.  UV light will not penetrate metals or opaque materials.  It can cause deterioration of some plastics and rubber materials.

Comment: @Nedd I've checked, and there isn't any adjacent water line. The bulb must really be for the lower storage compartment if it doesn't penetrate metals.